# Create Control in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

There is string array contains some file location.

I am using a foreach loop, in which each loop i want to create a new radio button control.
without foreach code performs, but in loop only one control is adding.

Can anybody tell me why? and how I perform this.

Code:

```
string[] location =
{
    @"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe",
    @"C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe",
    @"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
};

int i = 10;
foreach (string path in location)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        RadioButton rbList = new RadioButton();
        rbList.AutoSize = false;
        Icon icn;
        icn = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path);
        rbList.Image = icn.ToBitmap();
        rbList.Height = 100;
        rbList.Width = 50;
        i = i + 30;
        rbList.Location = new Point(100, i);

        groupBox1.Controls.Add(rbList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: you may want to call the SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout methods before and after you add the controls, if you're not doing it already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838315/c-why-use-suspendlayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the height to 100 but increase the position by 30 only.

```
rbList.Height = 100; 
...
i = i + 30;
rbList.Location = new Point(100, i);
```

You can decrease the height below 30:

```
rbList.Height = 30; //or smaller
```

or

increase the "i" more than 100:

```
i = i + 100; //or more than 100
rbList.Location = new Point(100, i);
```

Comment: thanx buddy, I got my fault. I need to improve my maths

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
rbList.AutoSize = true;
```

And be sure your groupBox1 is large enough to display all your radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit of changes:

```
i = i + 100;
rbList.Location = new Point(100, i);

groupBox1.Controls.Add(rbList);

int space = 10;
groupBox1.Height += rbList.Height + space;
```

This work without alignment, alignment is yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 10;
var radios = new[] { "", "", "" }
    .Where(path => File.Exists(path))
    .Select(path => new RadioButton
        {
            AutoSize = false,
            Image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path).ToBitmap(),
            Height = 100,
            Width = 50,
            Location = new Point(100, (i = i + 30))
        })
     .ToArray();

groupBox1.Controls.AddRange(radios);
```

Comment: Thanx... but in my case number of radio Buttons depends on the no of given paths. What if user gives more paths i.e. dynamically any number of RB could be used.

Comment: @Pawan: Then use not an explicitly declared array but an array passed as a parameter - returned by the user