# Why does hiding controls in WinForm take longer than making them visible?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` that contains 56 checkboxes. The checkboxes are used in three state mode. Now here is the fun part. If the check boxes are uncheked that means that they are not used and can be hidden for ease or reading. To hide them I use another checkbox. When to user clicks the checkbox all unused checkboxs in the FlowPanel are hidden using a foreach iteration.

The problem is that to hide them, that foreach call take (`checkBox.Visible=false`) about 2-3 seconds and to show them (`checkBox.Visible=true`) takes 0.5 seconds.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

```
private void hideUnusedPinsCheckBoxClick(objest sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bool state = !hideUnusedPinsCheckBox.Checked;
   foreach(object obj in flowLayoutPanel.Controls)
   {
      CheckBox cB = (CheckBox)obj;
      if(cB.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
         cB.Visible=state;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a "meta suggestion": Fetch a performance profiler of your choice (e.g. [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)) and measure what takes long.

Comment: I know that making them hidden takes longer that making them visible.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the loop with calls to [`SuspendLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) and `ResumeLayout` on `flowLayoutPanel`?

Comment: @RobertIagar Yes, that is what you are already stating in your question's title. My suggestion is to help you find out the "why".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that does work, but it's not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try calling `SuspendLayout` before hiding all your checkboxes, and then calling `ResumeLayout` afterwards. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838315/c-sharp-why-use-suspendlayout) for more.

The answer your question as to *why* this is happening. Each time you hide (or show) a control on the FlowLayoutPanel, the panels layouter algorithm is executed in order to rearrange everything on screen. If you hide for example 50 check boxes in a row, the layouter algorithm will execute at least 1,275 times. For example:

```
- Hide checkbox
- Perform layout for remaining 49 check boxes
- Hide checkbox
- Perform layout for remaining 48 check boxes
- Hide checkbox
- Perform layout for remaining 47 check boxes
- etc...
```

By calling SuspendLayout, the layouter algorithm does not run at all until you call ResumeLayout, reducing the number from 1,275 to 1.

Comment: See, I posted this as a comment, since it doesn't actually answer the question as posed...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, sorry didn't see that sooner. I re-picked the answer to the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RobertIagar I have amended the answer to explain why it was running slowly.

Answer (score 3):

If you hide something, the system must find out what is below that obect, and force that thing to redraw itself.

On the other hand, when you make a control visible, only that control must be drawn.

Comment: That means that if I do it reverse (beggining from the bottom layer) will that improve?

Comment: Not sure... better try the `SuspendLayout`-`ResumeLayout` approach, as proposed by MattDavey, first.

Comment: This answers the question. The fix is `SuspendLayout` - `ResumeLayout` approach.

Comment: This is not the cause of the problem, the cause is that the layout algorithm was running hundreds of times - this is why SuspendLayout fixed the issue. If redrawing was the cause SuspendLayout would have made no difference (SuspendLayout does not stop controls from redrawing).