# Difference between suspendlayout and resumelayout

Tags: c#, winforms

I read the following thread [Why use suspendLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3838315/139698) . So I thought I would create a small example that would give me proof of concept. But, it's not working. I only see "Part 2 completed".

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        lblStatus.Text = "Part 1 completed";
        this.ResumeLayout();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        this.SuspendLayout();
        lblStatus.Text = "Part 2 completed";
        this.ResumeLayout();            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've blocked the UI thread from executing with `Thread.Sleep()` (e.g. process WM_SETTEXT messages), therefore it can't update the UI to *show* "Part 1 completed".  It's only able to refresh itself after the UI thread has a resumed and by that time you've asked it to show "Part 2 completed"

If you wanted to simulate a period of time between changing a text box value, you could use a `Timer`.  For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
    label1.Text = "Part 1 completed";
    this.ResumeLayout();
    timer.Interval = 5000;
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    label1.Text = "Part 2 completed";
    this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Comment: but I set the label before going to sleep?

Comment: Setting the label is in fact sending a message to the control--if you block the UI thread (with `Thread.Sleep`) it can't process that message (WM_SETTEXT)

Comment: Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do above?