# How is Form1_Load() invoked by the Load event in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I'm a rookie in Windows Forms Applications. I have created a `Form` without any controls added. The following code is generated by the VS compiler

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(328, 301);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

I have found that `Load` is an event and the `Form1` class has `Form1_Load()` function with arguments. But I couldn't find how that function is invoked by the `Load` event. How does this call occur?

Answer (score 2):

An event has a certain signature, and the event handler must match this signature.

The default [`EventHandler` delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) has a signature of `object sender, EventArgs e`, so the event handler method must have this exact same signature:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

If it wouldn't, but for example simply be a parameterless method:

```
private void Form1_Load()
```

Then this code wouldn't compile:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

> No overload for 'Form1_Load' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

As for *who* is raising this event and *how* the arguments are assigned, that's the WinForms engine doing that for you.

Comment: Thank u for the reply. Can u please explain the use of SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() in the above code with an example ? I have run the program without these two functions. But it running as usual.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838315/c-sharp-why-use-suspendlayout

Answer (score -1):

It is called from the base class [`Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from which your this form class which you have created is inheriting.

If you see your form code it would be like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
}
```

The event [OnLoad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload(v=vs.110).aspx) is fired from within the `Form` base class which causes to invoke the method which we register with the `Load` property in our form.