# Dynamically added controls behave differently when added from onClick()

Tags: c#, forms, controls

I have a method that dynamically adds controls to a form. The issue is that when I call this method from the onClick as opposed to the initialize it doesn't behave as expected (weird spacings and controls sizes). What is causing this?

Code:
    private string fileName;

```
    private const int c_nameX = 12;
    private const int c_valueX = 198;
    private const int c_deltaY = 25;
    private System.Drawing.Size c_textBoxSize = new System.Drawing.Size(165, 22);
    private int v_parameterY;
    private int v_counter;

    /// <summary>
    /// default generated form constructor
    /// </summary>
    public CreateConfiguration()
    {
        v_parameterY = 121;
        v_counter = 0;
        AddParameter();
        //AddParameter();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// on click for adding a new parameter field
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void AddParameter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddParameter();
    }

    private void AddParameter()
    {
        string name = "A" + v_counter++.ToString();
        string value = "B" + v_counter++.ToString();

        TextBox A = new TextBox();
        A.Name = name;
        A.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);
        A.Size = c_textBoxSize;
        A.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(c_nameX, v_parameterY);
        A.Visible = true;

        TextBox B = new TextBox();
        B.Name = value;
        B.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);
        B.Size = c_textBoxSize;
        B.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(c_valueX, v_parameterY);
        B.Visible = true;

        Controls.Add(A);
        Controls.Add(B);

        v_parameterY += c_deltaY;
    }
```

Edit:
Image below. The first pair of textboxes is the functional call in the initializer the second row is from the onClick

[image]

Comment: `weird spacings and controls sizes` , can u provide an image of the current situation ?

Comment: Did you debug it to make sure c_valueX and v_parameterY were what you would have expected? If you did and they did not, [edit] to include the values you wanted and the values you got. And include an image (you can't add one yet, so stick it somewhere and linky and someone will edit it in for you).

Comment: @Will I added an image. Also I did check the debugger and everything looks normal there from what I can tell

Comment: Sounds like a job for SuspendLayout : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838315/c-sharp-why-use-suspendlayout

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea I added a SuspendLayout() at the beginning of AddParameter() and a ResumeLayout() at the end and it hasn't seemed to change anything

Comment: Calling that code *before* IntializeComponent looks suspicious.